# What are alternative words (or phrases) for "non-platonic/romantic/sexual", described those sorts of (or sides of) relationships?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, adjectives

Sometimes we want to specify that a relationship is not platonic, but rather romantic and/or sexual. At other times we want to refer to that aspect of a relationship. What are some others words or phrases that can be used to do so? The three words mentioned have the following issues which I'd prefer to avoid:

- 'Romantic' is a strong word which suggests love is present.
- By contast 'sexual' places the emphasis on sex in a way which may be inappropriate.
- Non-platonic avoids these issues, but is a bit stilted and formal.

Comment: Although *romantic* may sometimes be used in the way you describe, in contemporary English it often seems to be used merely to indicate the nature of one's interest in another person, without implying that one's feelings are particularly strong. In many everyday contexts it will be understood to carry precisely the meaning you intend.

Answer (score 2):

I basically think this is a zero sum game.

However, here are eight Greek ways to describe love so something should strike your fancy:

> **The Ancient Greeks had eight words that corresponded to different
> types of love:**

**Eros** (romantic, passionate love) The first kind of love

> is Eros, named after the Greek God of fertility. Eros is passion, lust
> and pleasure. The ancient Greeks considered Eros to be dangerous and
> frightening as it involves a “loss of control” through the primal
> impulse to procreate. Eros is an intense form of love that arouses
> romantic and sexual feelings.

**Philia** (affectionate love)

> The second type of love is Philia, or friendship. Plato felt that physical
> attraction was not a necessary part of love, hence the use of the word
> platonic to mean, “without physical attraction.”

**Agape** (selfless, universal love) The third is Agape, selfless universal love, such as the love for strangers, nature, or God. This

> love is unconditional, bigger than ourselves, a boundless compassion
> and an infinite empathy that you extended to everyone, whether they
> are family members or distant strangers.

**Storge** (familiar love) Storge is a natural form of affection

> experienced between family members. This protective, kinship-based
> love is common between parents and their children, and children for
> their parents. Storge can also describe a sense of patriotism toward a
> country or allegiance to the same team.

**Mania** (obsessive love)    When love turns to obsession, it becomes

> mania. Stalking behaviors, co-dependency, extreme jealousy, and
> violence are all symptoms of Mania.

**Ludus** (playful love) The Ancient Greeks thought of ludus as a playful

> form of love. It describes the situation of having a crush and acting
> on it, or the affection between young lovers.

**Pragma** (enduring love) Pragma is a love built on commitment,

> understanding and long-term best interests. It is a love that has
> aged, matured and about making compromises to help the relationship
> work over time, also showing patience and tolerance.

**Philautia** (self love) he Greeks understood that in order to care for

> others, we must first learn to care for ourselves.
>
> As Aristotle said “All friendly feelings for others are an extension
> of a man’s feelings for himself.”

[eight words for love from Ancient Greek](https://greekcitytimes.com/2020/02/14/the-8-ancient-greek-words-for-love/)

And to speed you on your way here's some great BAZOUKI MUSIC (to get into the Greek (modern) spirit):

[Bazouki music](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRy6U4H9nqw)

Comment: *Ludus* is good. And the English adjective 'ludic' is classy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What do you mean by saying that it's a zero sum game?

Comment: Isn't *ludus* a Latin word?

Answer (score 0):

Since aesthetic means 'capable of generating feelings', I would advocate for;

"An '***anaesthetic***' relationship".

Also on my list of alternates;  ***Quixotic***  (I really miss the 17th Century)

Comment: I don't think that would do, because of the usual medical meaning of _anaesthetic_ - it sounds as though the relationship sends you to sleep!

Comment: I must profoundly apologize;  I've been labouring under the misapprehension this site was to celebrate origins, history, folklore, complexity and nuance.  My education, training and experience has (mis?)led me down the path of Veracity, to the exclusion of peer pressure, public opinion and a construction I have eschewed, vis. "everybody knows".

Comment: @Kate Bunting  Could you please give me the usual meaning for the following;   ***right, good, evil, god, freedom, soul*** and, most importantly ***set***.

Comment: ??? I was merely pointing out that 99% of readers would associate the word with anaesthesia for a surgical operation!

Comment: It seems to be self-contradictory to say that a romantic/sexual relationship is not capable of generating feelings.